# When i run "gatsby develop " Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module error is showing

Tags: gatsby

> gatsby develop success openly and validate gatsby-configs - 0.005 s
>   error Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module The module
>   '\?\D:\korero\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node' was
>   compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION
>   64. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 79. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm
>   rebuild` or `npm install`).
>   - Ensure the version of Node.js used at install time matches that used at runtime
>   - Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/
>   - Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues ⠋ load plugins

Comment: Can you run `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install` again?

Comment: Clearing `node_modules` doesn't solve this problem. @ksav

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you have upgraded your NodeJS version? The sharp package was initially installed and built under a different node version as the error states.

Compiled against `NODE_MODULE_VERSION = 64` (NodeJS 10.x) while your current NodeJS expects `NODE_MODULE_VERSION = 79` which means you're using Node 13.

An easy fix would be to simply run:

```
npm rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/python3.8` if it exists

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/python3.9` if it exists

`brew upgrade`

remove any one if it exists:

`rm -rf package-lock.json`

`rm -rf yarn.lock`

`rm -rf node_modules`

Then `yarn install`

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` files and clearing cache (using `yarn cache clean` or `npm cache clean --force`.

lastly,

try updating your npm or node versions

`npm install npm@latest -g`

This worked for me