# MAC M1 Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, apple-m1, sharp

Running `npm run dev` (`gatsby develop`) on MacBook Pro M1 chip exit with   `Error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module`

Running `npm run dev`  MacBook Pro intel chip works fine.

I've seen similar post which did not solved my problem :

- [When i run "gatsby develop " Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module error is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317121/when-i-run-gatsby-develop-something-went-wrong-installing-the-sharp-module)
- [Error Installing Gatsby Starter 'Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997253/error-installing-gatsby-starter-something-went-wrong-installing-the-sharp-mod)
- [Gatsby Develop : Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64233792/gatsby-develop-something-went-wrong-installing-the-sharp-module)

I've update my node version in case any fixes had been made but I still got the error on `node v16.0.0`

On this [github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20957#issuecomment-579414671) they recommend to follow theses steps which did not work.

> ```
> rm -r node_modules/sharp
> yarn install --check-files
> ```

On this [github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24559) they recommend to install `NVM` and downgrade node version. NVM has some difficulties to install on my M1 chip so it is not a good option for me.

I have also tried to do the following steps which did not work as well

```
rm -rf node_module
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

Any idea what can I do to fix `gatsby develop` on M1 chip ?

Comment: up to 0.29 you can read in doc https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#apple-m1

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Following these steps from [this discussion](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/29891) solved my problem.

1. `xcode-select --install`
2. `brew install gcc`
3. `brew reinstall vips`
4. `brew info vips`
5. `npm i`

Then you can run `gatsby develop`

Answer (score 7):

Resolved by removing the current vips

```
brew remove vips
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
```

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2588#issuecomment-783254806

Answer (score 5):

I had to downgrade node from 17 (nvm is ideal here) - it worked on 14.

Comment: great solution - make sure you remove node_modules, downgrade to node 14, and then npm install again

Comment: this is the only missing answer from all other solutions, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I tried this command, it will probably workout for you too.
all you need to do is to install sharp with unsafe perm which gonna fix the error

```
npm install sharp --unsafe-perm
```

keep in mind that this just fix it for the time being and i suggest you to update the xcode command line tools for the main fix

Comment: This worked for me. Nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to add sharp as a resolution to solve dependencies incompatibilities like this:

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "sharp": "^0.29.0"
  }
}
```

I've found this and more solutions in https://github.com/nuxt/image/issues/204#issuecomment-1001585763